# compensate in sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I want to say that one should make good the loss of other. Can I say;

> I will compensate the damage from your payment.

If "from" in the sentence is ok, I have no further question. If it is not good there, please give some examples for providing the same meaning.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you will ADD TO the payment an amount to cover damages?  Or that you will DEDUCT FROM the payment an amount to cover the damages? In either case, one does not "compensate" to or from a _payment_; one compensates the PERSON who suffered the loss/damage (perhaps by _adjusting_ the payment.)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock "deduct from".

Comment: Can I say "my damage will be compensated by him" @BrianHitchcock

Comment: No, because you were not damaged, you wouldn't say "my damage"; and the other guy compensates **you**, not the damages.  Better to say "{**I** will be compensated by him / He will compensate **me**} FOR {**my** loss / **the** damage}."

Answer (score 2):

We would say:

I will compensate you for the damage by deducting the amount from what you owe.

I will deduct the amount of the damage from what you owe, to compensate you.

The total amount due on the invoice reflects a deduction of $_________, to compensate you for the damage.